# Why does infinite recursion result in segmentation fault instead of stack overflow?

Tags: c++, recursion, segmentation-fault

In GCC 4.8, why does the following code fragment:

```
  int foo() { return foo(); }
```

result in a segmentation fault instead of a stack overflow?

Comment: In GCC 4.8, why are you writing `int foo() { return foo(); }`?

Comment: Also note that a good compiler (like GCC) will automatically replace tail recursion with a loop in most cases. So I'm surprised that didn't happen here.

Comment: @Dave Well, if this is being done as a learning exercise (which I assume it is, as nobody would deliberately write code like that), then the OP probably disabled optimizations.